# How to pass Generic Type to component imported with Next.js Dynamic?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, lazy-loading, typescript-generics

This is no error with this code:

```js
import DatasheetContainer from '@/uikit/detailed-view/DatasheetContainer';

const DetailedView = () => {

  return (
    <Page>
      <PageBody direction="row" bgColor="white">
        <DatasheetContainer<Subject>
        />
      </PageBody>
    </Page>
  );
};

export default DetailedView;
```

But, when I use next dynamic, ts give an error

```js
const DatasheetContainer = dynamic(
  () => import('@/uikit/detailed-view/DatasheetContainer'),
);

const DetailedView = () => {

  return (
    <Page>
      <PageBody direction="row" bgColor="white">
        <DatasheetContainer<Subject>
        />
      </PageBody>
    </Page>
  );
};

export default DetailedView;
```

The error is `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.` on `<DatasheetContainer<Subject>`

How to properly pass the type in next dynamic?

Comment: Try this one. `const DatasheetContainer = dynamic<Subject>(
  () => import('@/uikit/detailed-view/DatasheetContainer'),
);`. I think you can share it via sandbox to get proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve that like this

```js
const DatasheetContainer = dynamic(
  () => import('@/uikit/detailed-view/DatasheetContainer'),
) as <DataType extends Record<string, unknown>>({ prop1, prop2 }: DatasheetContainerProps<DataType>) => JSX.Element
```